# When is the set of rationalizable strategies a proper subset of the set that survives IEDS?

Tags: game-theory

When is the set of rationalizable strategies smaller than the set of strategies surviving Iterated removal of strictly dominated strategies. Mas Collel Page 243, claims set of rationalizable strategies can be no larger than the latter, and I am sure they coincide in 2x2 games. What would be an example when they do not coincide for a larger game?